# How to cast a Proxy to an interface? (or tell Proxy to implement an interface)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I need ActionScript Proxy to be castable to a particular interface.

Here is an example without interface:

```
public dynamic class Tracer extends Proxy {
    flash_proxy override function callProperty(method:*, ... args):* {
        trace(method + " " + args)
    }
}

var t:* = new Tracer()
t.sayHello("123") // prints: "sayHello [123]"
```

Now I need "t" to be of Talker type (don't ask why, I just love static typing):

```
public interface Talker {
    function sayHello(s:String):void
}

var t:Talker = new Tracer() // throws class cast exception
t.sayHello("123")
```

**The question is: how to cast a proxy?**

For example, a solution for Java would be passing a list of interfaces when you create a new Proxy http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Is it really possible with ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's unfortunately not possible in plain actionscript. But I think you can do it with the [as commons bytecode API](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html).

Comment: I do believe you're right, and if I'm not mistaking, this scenario is shown right on that page mentioned above. Looks like it can do quite a bit of interesting Class / Interface manipulations. Good find!

Answer (score 0):

what about declaring `public dynamic class Tracer extends Proxy implements Talker` with all methods that need to be defined?

Comment: Then the whole idea of Proxy becomes useless -- a Proxy is needed to get rid of methods, not to implement them.

Comment: @ oshyshko - then why do you need an interface? my only idea was about code completion, but if you need it - you'll have to define methods anyway (imho the best way is to create a class extending `Proxy` and wrap it into a class implementing an interface). btw here's another way http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/10/multiple-inheritance-in-actionscript-3.cfm

Comment: I will never define methods for the interface -- they will be implemented by a Proxy. All what I need is a way to pass my interface (Talker) to Proxy and get an instance back (created by Proxy) which can be casted back to Talker (should implement the interface) and used as any regular implementation, but produced by Proxy, not a programmer. Now it can't be casted, it's just (dynamic) Object.

Comment: @ oshyshko - did you try `var t:Tracer = new Tracer();
(t as Talker).sayHello("123");`? by the way i'm not sure if a class without every interface method defined can implement one